# Stay connected to ble when app is closed

Tags: ios7, ios8, ibeacon

I have one BLE device which has one physical button on it ,I want to trigger local notification  in iOS device whenever I click the BLE device button  even when the app is closed .Is this is possible in iOS to read characterstics event when the app is closed.

Thanks

Comment: It all depends on how that device works.  You need to post technical details about how it advertises itself and what changes when you hit the button.

Comment: When I hit the button of ble device it will change the characteristics of service ,and i Just want a local notification in iOS device when i hit button.

Comment: In other words ,in my ble device there is temperature sensor so whenever the temperature is changed can I receive a local notification in my iOS device even if the app is closed ,Can you please help me on this @davidgyoung sir

Comment: @DAMM108 did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @swalkner I'm facing some problem . Did you find a solution ?